# How to keep old rotation even after setting new rotation in android

Tags: android, view, rotation

How can i keep my old rotation with new rotation using view.setRotation method.
I am new to android rotation please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to rotate view relative to it's current rotation? For example, first rotate to 10 degrees, and then to 20, and get 30 degree rotation in result?

Comment: If I'm right, then you need to `view.setRotation(view.getRotation() + newRotation);`